Is probability physical or idealistic? Is probability an inherent part of nature/reality?
I asked this question a while back: Is entropy physical or idealistic?
Now, I am back to ask if the subject that entropy built around is inherently real i.e., probability in itself being inherent not just in entropy but as a phenomena by itself or rather is it just an idealistic tool developed by humans because of uncertainty?
Is there a deeper understanding of probability that makes it as inherently real to nature itself or is it a product of thought and uncertainty?
Edit: To focus the type of probability I am talking about Propensity interpretation of probability, is this interpretation still not a result of our ideas and thoughts rather than it being naturally real?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It is both physical and idealistic. For example, if a dice is rolled repeatedly, on average each number will come up around a sixth of the time. That tendency is physical. The language of probability we use to model such tendencies is idealistic. A key difference between the idealistic and the physical, is that the former tends to be based on assumptions- such as perfectly fair dice, infinite numbers of throws etc- which are only approximately satisfied in reality.

Good clarification!

Probability is an epistemic description of ontic uncertainty.
Probability is what is known about an uncertain outcome of which complete knowledge is not available or does not yet exist.

Seems pretty straightforward. Apparently there is disagreement over whether some kinds of information might forever be "not available", whether knowledge of a future state might be impossible even in principle.

I am not aware of

Coin flips are impossible to predict before the actual flip. After that it is too late. The randomness has already happened.

Probability is epistemic, not physical (with a caveat). It is a description of how much an agent doesn't know about an event, or how much an agent would know about the event if they fully correlated the knowledge they do have. The caveat is that the agent is also physical, so probability can be said to be a physical property of the (agent, event) pair. But it's not a physical property of just the event, if you take out the agent.
If you flip a coin, perhaps the probability it will land heads is 50%. But perhaps someone nearby has a high-speed camera hooked up to a physics simulator, so they can determine how the coin will land while it's still in the air with 95% certainty. Then, for the person with the camera, at time T = "a half second after the coin leaves the flipper's hand," the chance the coin will land heads is, say, 95%. For the person flipping the coin, the chance at time T that it will land heads is only 50%.
The epistemic interpretation of probability still works when we get to quantum mechanics. Even if you subscribe to the Copenhagen interpretation and claim QM probabilities are "intrinsic," what this means operationally is that there's a limit on how well scientists can predict the outcome.
It's likely that the many-worlds interpretation of QM is correct. (It's a fairly popular interpretation among physicists, second to Copenhagen). If so, what this means is that the world is fully deterministic, with no wave-function collapse at all, and it branches simultaneously towards all possible futures. In this scenario, all probabilities are merely a reflection of the scientists' lack of knowledge. And this lack of knowledge likely cannot ever be overcome; we are physically limited from knowing which branch we're going to take, because the fact is we take all of them. Nonetheless, the universe under many-worlds is deterministic and the probabilities express the scientists' lack of knowledge.
Thermodynamic entropy, though it may seem to be a physical quantity, depends on the probability distribution of system microstates and thus also depends on how much you know. Maxwell's Demon would be a hypothetical entity that exploits its knowledge of the trajectories of individual gas molecules to extract work from the gas. This is because the information-theoretic entropy of the gas is lower for Maxwell's Demon than it is for humans. In real life we don't have demons, but it is still possible to convert information about a thermodynamic system into useful work. A device that does this is called an information engine:

Here, we designed an engine that stores energy by raising a bead against gravity, driven purely by information about the bead position.

The fact that information engines work proves that thermodynamic entropy depends on what the agent knows about the system, and so it cannot be purely a property of the system.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
